# Вместо введенных слов отображаются символы

Tags: java

Есть программа-каталог напитков. Почему введенные пользователем данные, а именно, название и тип на консоли отображаются всякими символами? И как это исправить?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class Katalog
{
    static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Double> percent = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Выберите действие: ");
            System.out.println("1 - показать весь каталог");
            System.out.println("2 - добавить новый напиток в каталог");
            System.out.println("3 - поиск напитка с минимальной ценой при крепости не ниже заданной");
            int choose = in.nextInt();
            switch(choose)
            {
                case 1: printall(); break;
                case 2: add(); break;
                case 3: found_minimum(); break;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    static void printall()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
            System.out.println(printone(i));
    }
    static String printone(int i)
    {
        return "Наименование: " + name.get(i)+ " - Тип " + type.get(i) +" - Спирта " + percent.get(i)+ "%.";
    }
    static void add()
    {
        System.out.println("Введите наименование: ");
        name.add(in.next());
        System.out.println("Введите тип: ");
        type.add(in.next());
        System.out.println("Введите процентное содержание спирта: ");
        percent.add(in.nextDouble());
    }

    static void found_minimum()
    {
        System.out.println("Введите нижний предел процента содержания спирта: ");
        double limit = in.nextDouble();
        Boolean found = false;
        if(percent.size()>1)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            double max = percent.get(0);
            for(int i=0;i<percent.size();i++)
                if(percent.get(i)>max){
                    max=percent.get(i);pos=i;}
            double min = max;
            if(min>=limit)
            {
                found = true;
                for(int i=0;i<percent.size();i++)
                    if(percent.get(i)<min && percent.get(i)>=limit){
                        min=percent.get(i);pos=i;}
            }
            if(found)
                System.out.println("Минимальный по проценту содержания спирта: " + printone(pos));
            else
                System.out.println("Такого напитка нет!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: программа запускаеться на ОС Windows?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , на Windows

Answer (score 0):

Внутреннее представление строк в Java - unicode. Кодировка строк в исходном коде, скорее всего - utf-8. Кодировка консоли Windows - cp866. В процессе конкатенации строк с разной кодировкой получаются крякозяблы. Беду эту можно подпереть костыликом:

```
public class Katalog
{
    static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Double> percent = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String consoleEncoding = System.getProperty("console.encoding",
            os.startsWith("Windows") ? "cp866" : "utf-8");
        in = new Scanner(System.in, consoleEncoding);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Выберите действие: ");
            System.out.println("1 - показать весь каталог");
            System.out.println("2 - добавить новый напиток в каталог");
            System.out.println("3 - поиск напитка с минимальной ценой при крепости не ниже заданной");
            System.out.println("4 - выход");
            int choose = in.nextInt();
            switch(choose)
            {
                case 1: printall(); break;
                case 2: add(); break;
                case 3: found_minimum(); break;
                case 4: return;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    // Остальное без изменений
}
```

В Windows строки будут считываться в кодировке cp866, в других операционных системах в utf-8. В случае необходимости переопределить это автоопределение можно ключом `-Dconsole.encoding` при запуске программы.